# Tangent plane to a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the Plane M defined by the equation 6x-9y+18z=36.

a) Find the equation of a sphere entered at C (9,3,6) such that the plane M is tangent to the sphere

b) Find the equation of a plane that is tangent to the sphere from part (a) **and** perpendicular to plane M

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me with this problem. I have not learned gradient or partial differentiation so those are not allowed on this problem (as I saw online similar questions might be solved using those methods), so I was wondering if there is any other methods that could solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: For a) you need to find the radius. This will be the distance from the centre to the plane. For b) there are many planes that satisfy the requirements. What can you say about the plan normals if the planes are 'perpendicular'?

Comment: thank you I got part a)! And for b, if planes are perpendicular the normals must be perpendicular, which makes there dot product equal 0...I am not sure what to do from that?

Comment: Pick a normal that is perpendicular, find the point where the line through the centre in the direction of the new normal intersects the plane (at the edge of the sphere). Then you have a direction and a point on the plane.

Comment: For the normal vector <a,b,c> I got 6a-9b+18c=0, so do I just pick any values for a,b,c as long as they satisfy that equation? Also for finding the intersection points do I need to use the parametric vector line equations and subtitute those into the sphere equations from a? Thanks!